# Swipe to delete animation kills thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm rather new to iOS programming, and when I added swipe to delete functionality to the basic tutorial app, it crashes when I use the default command. Currently, I remove the object from the NSMutableArray that it's connected to and reload the data:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.toDoItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

the problem with this is that I don't get any sort of animation on deletion. Any suggestions on how to fix this are welcome.

Comment: You need to do deleteRowsAtIndexPaths after your removeObjectAtIndex. deleteRowsAtIndexPaths does the animation for you.

Comment: Do the deleteRowsAtIndexPath after the removeObjectAtIndex and don't do the reloadData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove your data object and then delete the row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.toDoItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```